# Have click on buttons trigger key presses

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to create "Correct" and "Incorrect" buttons that trigger key presses of 'c' and 'i' respectively. I am working with a jspsych plugin that can only accept key press responses. The buttons are showing up but my code is throwing an unexplained error every time I click one (and not triggering the key presses).

```
var simulateCorrectKeyPress = function(character) {
    jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : character.charCodeAt(0)});
}

$(function() {
    $('body').keypress(function(e) {
        alert(e.which);
    });
    simulateCorrectKeyPress('c');
});

var simulateIncorrectKeyPress = function(character) {
    jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : character.charCodeAt(0)});
}

$(function() {
    $('body').keypress(function(e) {
        alert(e.which);
    });

    simulateIncorrectKeyPress('i');
}); 

var correct_button = "<div> <button type='button' onclick='simulateCorrectKeyPress('c')'> Correct </button> </div>";


var incorrect_button = "<div> <button type='button' onclick='simulateIncorrectKeyPress('i')'> Incorrect </button> </div>";
```

Comment: What is the error that it's throwing?

Answer (score 2):

```
var correct_button = "<div> <button type='button' onclick='simulateCorrectKeyPress('c')'> Correct </button> </div>";
var incorrect_button = "<div> <button type='button' onclick='simulateIncorrectKeyPress('i')'> Incorrect </button> </div>";
```

The single-quotes in the `onclick` attribute are ending the attribute, so the rest of your `onclick` attribute runs off into the HTML tag.

You're only listening for the `keypress` event on the `body` element. You need to listen for `keypress` on the whole `window`.

Change this: `$('body').keypress(function(e) {`

To this: `$(window).keypress(function(e) {`

You also have two occurrences of duplicate code.

```
$('body').keypress(function(e) {
    alert(e.which);
});
```

This piece of code is repeated twice in your script. It's going to alert the `e.which` twice in a row.

You have a `simulateCorrectKeyPress()` function as well as a `simulateIncorrectKeyPress()` function. It's better to have one function for both `keypress` scenarios, since the function code is exactly the same in each one.

```
var simulateCorrectKeyPress = function(character) {
    jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : character.charCodeAt(0)});
}
var simulateIncorrectKeyPress = function(character) {
    jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : character.charCodeAt(0)});
}
// Seriously?
```

Or you can keep your two functions, but make them take no arguments.

```
simulateIncorrectKeyPress('i'); simulateCorrectKeyPress('c'); // Seriously?
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/wivanojuqo/edit?html,console,output

Hey,

```
$('body').keypress(function(e) {
```

you can't listen for a keypress on body. You need to attach this to window.

See the jsbin link - I guess it's all pretty clear. Otherwise you're code was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your quoting is incorrect. The single quotes before `c` and `i` are ending the attribute instead of delimiting the arguments. You need to use double quotes so they don't conflict. The double quotes need to be escaped so they don't end the HTML strings.

```
var correct_button = "<div> <button type='button' onclick='simulateCorrectKeyPress(\"c\")'> Correct </button> </div>";

var incorrect_button = "<div> <button type='button' onclick='simulateIncorrectKeyPress(\"i\")'> Incorrect </button> </div>";
```

`$('body').keypress()` bindings also don't seem right. These will be run in response to the keypress event, but then they trigger the event again, which results in a loop. And why do you have two of them, which each trigger the keypress event with a different code? I think you should just remove those bindings entirely, I assume the jspsych plugin has its own keypress handler that `simulateXXXKeyPress` will invoke.